# moq c# ilogger log mock setup

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, moq

Can someone please help me understand why is the last parameter a function here ?

You all might already be aware of extension methods not being supported for moq setup etc., I found something that helps me moq the .log method.

It does not work with It.IsAny<object[]>() as the last parameter where log expects params object[] args

https://taurit.pl/moq-extension-methods-may-not-be-used-in-setup-verification-expressions/#comment-372

this.mockLogger.Setup(x => x.Log(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny(), It.IsAny<It.IsAnyType>(), It.IsAny(),
(Func<It.IsAnyType, Exception, string>)It.IsAny()));

Thanks!

Comment: _Function to create a String message of the state and exception_ - [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.logging.ilogger.log?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured ilogger accepts the function as input parameter and since I was navigating to the definition(ctrl+f12) it takes me to LoggerExtensions vs ILogger that was supposed to be moqed. Since internally its the ilogger log that gets called in the end.